# Value from dynamic table (Cypress)

Tags: automation, cypress, e2e-testing

I need to take a value from a table that changes after every page refresh. For example CPU for Chrome

```js
describe('test dynamic table and check Chrome CPU', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('some url')
    cy.contains('span', 'CPU')
      .parent()
      .within(() => {
        cy.contains('[role=cell]', 'Chrome')
      })
  })
})
```

Table:

[image: table image]

UPDATE:
FYI
After refreshing the page, you will get columns and row changing place:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKX5K.png)

Comment: What do you want to do with the CPU Value ?

Comment: I need to take value from the table and check it with constant value. I just can't understand how I can take value from table if columns and rows change their places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Chrome')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('[role=cell]', '%')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text) => {
        cy.log(text) //Logs 8.3%

        //removing % and converting into number and asserting
        expect(+text.replace(/%/g, '')).to.be.greaterThan(5)
        expect(+text.replace(/%/g, '')).to.be.lessThan(15)
        expect(+text.replace(/%/g, '')).to.eq(8.3)
      })
  })
```

Comment: it isn't work, because table change when you refresh page (row and columns change place too)

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the table after a refresh, so that it gives me an idea, of what changes?

Comment: Update my question